# Make a div floats regardless of its content

Tags: html, css, width

I have two div with float left each.
When the content of the second div is too long, this div goes under the first block.
http://jsfiddle.net/Xuqv4/

```
#one {
float : left;
}

#two {
float : left;
margin-left : 10px;
}
```

But what i want, is that this div remains on the right of the other, regardless of its content.

The only way i found is to fix his width, but i cant in my site. The div should occupy all the available space.

Maybe you can help me ?
Many thanks :)

EDIT : The #two div has not fixed width.

Comment: You're showing #two as having a fixed width above - do you mean that #one cannot have a fixed width?

Comment: I'm really sorry, it's an error of copy/past. #two can't have a fixed width. The answer of j08691 above works well :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of floating the divs, set the display to table-cell:

```
div {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Xuqv4/3/)**